# Vertical oriented, right-to-left JList for Chinese text

Tags: java, jlist

Is this possible?

I wish I could show you my code, but I don't know where to start. I haven't found a single example on google.

If it is possible, could someone please reference me to a sample?

```
LstGlossary.setModel(
new javax.swing.AbstractListModel() { String[] strings = { "你好", "哈囉" }; 
public int getSize() { return strings.length; } 
public Object getElementAt(int i) { return strings[i]; } 
}); 
LstGlossary.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIG‌​HT_TO_LEFT);
```

Here's what these two strings look like with vertical text orientation going right to left in Microsoft Word:

[image: Vertical, Right to Left Chinese Text]

Comment: You could try using Java FX instead of Swing, and putting `{ -fx-rotate:90; }` in the CSS.  I can't guarantee it will work, but it's worth a shot.

Comment: You could try [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32817535/4668606). I've written it a bit of time ago and it's for `JMenus`, but it should work for `JLists` as well.

Comment: Unfortunately the whole program is already in Swing, and it's quite a large one. I just need this one component to change. I was thinking it may be possible if I change from a JList to a JTable though?

Comment: @Paul It just made the text look right-aligned. The order of the text didn't change for Chinese (Ie. Hi didn't change to iH, nor did it change to H \n I)

Answer (score 2):

Use the `setComponentOrientation` method:

```
jlist.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
```

From the Javadoc:

> Sets the language-sensitive orientation that is to be used to order
>   the elements or text within this component. Language-sensitive
>   LayoutManager and Component subclasses will use this property to
>   determine how to lay out and draw components.

Comment: LstGlossary.setModel(new javax.swing.AbstractListModel() {
    String[] strings = { "你好", "哈囉" };
    public int getSize() { return strings.length; }
    public Object getElementAt(int i) { return strings[i]; }
});
LstGlossary.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);    //This just gives me right-aligned Chinese text. It doesn't change it to vertical text oriented text, like (你 \n 好)

Comment: Though this would probably get the list elements to run right to left if I just had some way of getting each element to run vertically instead of horizontally.